# Attach the events ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() only to the current backbone view

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm using backbone for an app that I'm building. In this app, I have a master view which render a template with 2 other views inside. One header view and another one with some content. The header view is just used to interact with the content view and has specific functions too.

In the header template and content template I have the same piece of code, an hidden DIV with a loader image that is displayed when an ajax call is made. The problem I have is that when I load the app for the first time (or when I refresh the content view), the content view is loading some data from an ajax request, but the loader is showing up in both the header and the content template (like if the ajaxStart() was a global event not attached to the view.

Here is the content view setup:

> ```
> App.View.Content = Backbone.View.extend({
>         type:'test',
>         template: twig({
>             href: '/js/app/Template/Content.html.twig',
>             async: false
>         }),
>         block:{
>             test:twig({
>                 href: '/js/app/Template/block/test.html.twig',
>                 async: false
>             })
>         },
>         list:[],
>
>         showLoader: function(el){
>             console.log('loader: ', $('#ajax_loader', el));
>             $('#ajax_loader', el).show();
>             console.log('Ajax request started...');
>         },
>
>         hideLoader: function(el){
>             $('#ajax_loader', el).hide();
>             console.log('Ajax request ended...');
>         },
>
>         initialize: function(params)
>         {
>             this.el   = params.el;
>             this.type = params.type || this.type;
>             var self  = this;
>
>             this.el
>                 .ajaxStart(function(){self.showLoader(self.el);})
>                 .ajaxStop(function(){self.hideLoader(self.el);});
>
>             this.render(function(){
>                 self.list = new App.Collection.ListCollection();
>                 self.refresh(1, 10);
>             });
>         },
>
>     refresh:function(page, limit)
>     {
>         var self = this;
>         console.log('Refreshing...');
>
>         $('#id-list-content').fadeOut('fast', function(){
>             $(this).html('');
>         });
>
>         this.list.type  = this.type;
>         this.list.page  = page || 1;
>         this.list.limit = limit || 10;
>
>         this.list.fetch({
>             success: function(data){
>                 //console.log(data.toJSON());
>
>                 $.each(data.toJSON(), function(){
>                     //console.log(this.type);
>                     var tpl_block = self.block[this.type];
>                     if (tpl_block != undefined) {
>                         var block = tpl_block.render({
>                             test: this
>                         });
>                         $(block).appendTo('#id-list-content');
>                     }
>                 });
>
>                 $('#id-list-content').fadeIn('fast');
>             }
>         });
>     },
>
>     render: function(callback)
>     {
>         console.log('Rendering list...');
>         this.el.html(this.template.render({
>
>         }));
>
>         if (undefined != callback) {
>             callback();
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

As you can see I'm using an ugly piece of code to attach the ajaxStart / ajaxStop event:

```
this.el
    .ajaxStart(function(){self.showLoader(self.el);})
    .ajaxStop(function(){self.hideLoader(self.el);});
```

I use to have it like this:

```
this.el
    .ajaxStart(self.showLoader())
    .ajaxStop(self.hideLoader());
```

But for whatever reason that still undefined on my end, `this.el` was not defined in the `showLoader()` and `hideLoader()`.

I was thinking that `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` was attached to the `this.el` DOM, and that only this view would be able to listen to it. But my headerView which has exactly the same setup (except for the twig template loaded) apparently receive the event and show the loader.

To be sure of this behavior, I've commented out the `showLoader()` in the content view, and the loader still show up in the header view.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

**EDIT (after answer from "mu is too short"):**

my content view does now looks like this:

```
showLoader: function(){
            //this.$('#ajax_loader').show();
            console.log('Ajax request started...');
        },

        hideLoader: function(){
            this.$('#ajax_loader').hide();
            console.log('Ajax request ended...');
        },

        initialize: function(params)
        {
            var self  = this;

            console.log(this.el);

            _.bindAll(this, 'showLoader', 'hideLoader');

            this.$el
                .ajaxStart(this.showLoader)
                .ajaxStop(this.hideLoader);

            this.render(function(){
                self.list = new App.Collection.List();
                self.refresh(1, 10);
            });
        },
...

render: function(callback)
        {
            console.log('Rendering post by page...');
            this.$el.html(this.template.render({

            }));

            if (undefined != callback) {
                callback();
            }
}
```

and my header view:

```
...
showLoader: function(){
            this.$('#ajax_loader').show();
            //console.log('Ajax request started...');
        },

        hideLoader: function(el){
            this.$('#ajax_loader').hide();
            console.log('Ajax request ended...');
        },

        initialize: function(params)
        {
            var self = this;
            _.bindAll(this, 'showLoader', 'hideLoader');

            this.$el
                .ajaxStart(this.showLoader)
                .ajaxStop(this.hideLoader);

            this.models.Link = new App.Model.Link();
            this.render();
        },

        render: function(callback)
        {
            this.$el.html(this.template.render({
                data: []
            }));

            if (undefined != callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
...
```

But the loader still showing up in the header view template

PS: `this.showLoader()` was not a typo as I wanted to call the function within the current backbone view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context (AKA `this`) for a JavaScript function depends on how the function is called, not on the context in which the function is defined. Given something like this:

```
var f = o.m;
f();
```

When you call `o.m` through the plain function `f`, `this` inside `o.m` will usually be the global context (`window` in a browser). You can also use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to choose a different `this` so this:

```
f.call(o);
```

would make `this` the `o` that you'd expect it to be. I should mention that you can force your choice of `this` using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in most JavaScript environments but I don't want to get too sidetracked.

The point is that this:

```
this.el
    .ajaxStart(this.showLoader)
    .ajaxStop(this.hideLoader);
```

isn't enough to ensure that `showLoader` and `hideLoader` will run in the right context; I'm also assuming that the parentheses you had at the end of `showLoader` and `hideLoader` were just typos.

The most common way to force a context in a Backbone application is to use [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) in your `initialize`:

```
initialize: function(params) {
    _.bindAll(this, 'showLoader', 'hideLoader');
    //...
```

That essentially replaces `this.showLoader` and `this.hideLoader` with something that's, more or less, equivalent to your wrappers:

```
function() { self.showLoader(self.el) }
```

Once you have that `_.bindAll` in place, this:

```
this.el
    .ajaxStart(this.showLoader)
    .ajaxStop(this.hideLoader);
```

will work fine.

---

BTW, you don't need to do this:

```
this.el = params.el;
```

in your `initialize`, Backbone [does that for you](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...] There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

And you don't need to do things like this:

```
$('#ajax_loader', el).show();
```

either, Backbone gives you a [`$` method](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) in your view that does the same thing without hiding the `el` at the end of the argument list; doing it like this:

```
this.$('#ajax_loader').show();
```

is more idiomatic in Backbone.

Furthermore, `this.el` won't necessarily be a jQuery object so don't do this:

```
this.el.html(this.template.render({ ... }));
```

in your `render`, use the cached [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) instead:

```
this.$el.html(this.template.render({ ... }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response but the loader still showing up in the header template :(

Comment: From what I can read in the doc (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) `ajaxStart()` is a global event. it's triggered each time there is an ajax request. You can't do `$(DOM).ajaxStart(function(){console.log('triggered')});` and expect the ajax request being trigger by the DOM element. Am I right? I there any solution to my problem :( ?

Comment: @maxwell2022: Right, `$(x).ajaxStart()` is a lie since it really means `$(anything_at_all).ajaxStart()`. You'd have to bind to the specific AJAX calls you want either through the `$.ajax` arguments or through the returned `jqXHR`.

Comment: Because it's the collection which is triggering the ajax call magically when I fetch it, I can't bind it with $.ajax, could I?
Also, if I have 20 ajax calls per view I want to trigger only one event that I bind into the view to display the same loader.

Comment: A collection's [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) has success and error callbacks that you might be able to use. You can also provide your own `sync` and `fetch` methods if you wanted to add a "starting fetch" event of some sort. I'd usually put up the loader before doing the `fetch` and then the loader would go away when `render` got called after `fetch` finished fetching.

Comment: I've ended up having one loader for all the views. The loader is handle by the main view. Thanks for your help ;) Sorry I can't really accept the answer as there is no proper solution using `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()`

Comment: @maxwell2022: That's fair, I think I got a bit sidetracked anyway. You can answer your own question and accept that answer, that's allowed.